# How to read data in C that has format like "123 35 123 0 0 0 817"

Tags: c, io

I want to read data from a string. The string is like this:

```
"123 35   123 0    0      0       817 0    0   0   0"
```

there are a few numbers and spaces which is uncertain in the string. I want to read the third number. How to read data?

Comment: ... use an embeddable scripting language (like Lua) that doesn't make string handling a nightmare. Or alternatively use the good old, security-flawed, `scanf` ;)

Comment: A string literal? A string from a file stream? What are the requirements of this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `sscanf()`. It will skip whitespace.

```
int a, b, c;
if( sscanf(string, "%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c) == 3)
  printf("the third number is %d\n", c);
```

You can also use `%*` to suppress assignment of the two first numbers:

```
int a;
if( sscanf(string, "%*d %*d %d", &a) == 1)
  printf("the third number is %d\n", a);
```

Note that `sscanf()` returns the number of successful conversions (and assignments) it made, which is why the return value must be checked *before* relying on the values of the output variables.

Comment: This has no more information than my answer, and it's 30 seconds later, so -1 for a dupe.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII in all fairness, Stack Overflow probably didn't alert unwind that your answer had been posted - that feature isn't instantaneous.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Your answer doesn't show how to check the return value of `sscanf()`, it just claims that the conversion "magically" succeeds, which is not true. I consider checking the return value crucial. I've edited my answer to clarify that.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII -1 for dupe? That's not a valid reason. And 30 seconds later? How long have you been at SO?

Answer (score 2):

[`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) was designed just for this, specifically the `*` modifier to discard inputs:

```
const char *input = "...";
int value;

// here we use the '*' modifier to discard the input from our string
sscanf("%*i %*i %i", &value);

// value now magically has the value you need.
```

`sscanf` does have it's downsides, however. Whilst it does discard whitespace as you need it to, it is also traditionally slow. If you can, I would use `strtol` instead, which is faster (because it doesn't need to parse the format string).

Comment: @JimBalter there is no set time that it will save. But on most platforms in most situations, strtol has been tested to be up to 3x faster than sscanf. I would do testing on your platform to see if it makes a difference at all.

Comment: "premature optimization is the root of all evil" -- Donald Knuth.

Comment: @JimBalter maybe so, but when you develop games for systems with limited resources (in my case, iPhone & android) every nanosecond counts.

Comment: Instead of strtol you should consider optimized asm.

Comment: @JimBalter what platform are you designing for where there's a simple assembly instruction to convert a string to an integer? If that's true, then let me get some of that!